# How to create Pull Request on stash(Bitbucket Server) by jenkins plugins or command lines

Tags: jenkins-plugins, bitbucket-server

I've installed `Stash pullrequest builder plugin`. This plugin is used to build Pull Request by reading the [official introduction](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Stash+pullrequest+builder+plugin?showComments=true&showCommentArea=true#addcomment).

But I wanna know whether this plugin will create a specific Pull Request on **stash**. If not, how could I create by other plugins or by command lines or manually on stash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Stash REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/stash/3.11.3/stash-rest.html) to create a pull request with a command line.

You have to send a json post request to this url:

```
/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/pull-requests
```

Example with Curl:

```
curl -u your_stash_user:your_stash_password -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{JSON CONTENT}' http://your_stash_url/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/pull-requests
```

Json file (copied from the Atlassian doc):

```
{
    "title": "Talking Nerdy",
    "description": "It’s a kludge, but put the tuple from the database in the cache.",
    "state": "OPEN",
    "open": true,
    "closed": false,
    "fromRef": {
        "id": "refs/heads/feature-ABC-123",
        "repository": {
            "slug": "my-repo",
            "name": null,
            "project": {
                "key": "PRJ"
            }
        }
    },
    "toRef": {
        "id": "refs/heads/master",
        "repository": {
            "slug": "my-repo",
            "name": null,
            "project": {
                "key": "PRJ"
            }
        }
    },
    "locked": false,
    "reviewers": [
        {
            "user": {
                "name": "charlie"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```